# Use of two should in a simple sentence

Tags: grammar, should

[image: Is Headline correct? Can we use two should in a simple sentence?]

Is Headline correct? Can we use two should in a simple sentence

Answer (score 2):

No, it's a typo. I suspect some of these text-overs have to be put together very quickly; somebody just slipped and didn't catch it before it went on-air.